# Can decompactification explain the inflation of the early universe?

Tags: string-theory, cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation, compactification

I've just reread chapter 11 of [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465028373) book where it is explained among other things, that our four dimensional universe could be unstable concerning a decompactification transition, since potential energy is needed to keep the extra dimensions rolled up.

Are there some cosmological models that make use of this mechanism to explain the inflation of the early universe?